# Nested conditional statements (if, switch then if again)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question: is this kind of nesting possible?
An if statement first passing a switch and then another if statement so it won't affect other values that were not caught on switch?

```
var cookie = ""; //some value previously setted by filtering a cookie, like a product id
var prod = "";
var img = "";
if ((cookie != null) && (prod != '')) {
    switch (cookie) {
    case '001': case '002': case '003':
        prod = "Product01";
        img = "product01.jpg"
        break;
    case '004': case '005': case '006':
        prod = "Product02";
        img = "product02.jpg"
        break;
    case '007': case '008':
        prod = "Product03";
        img = "product03.jpg"
        break;
    case 'null':
        break;
    }
    if (window.location.pathname == 'somepage') {
        //jQuery code
    } else if (window.location.pathname == 'anotherpage') {
        //jQuery code
    } else {
        //jQuery code
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try it out?

Comment: Looks fine to me, are you getting errors?

Comment: It's not fine. I see closing parenthesis missing. i.e. `if(jQuery(window.location.pathname == 'somepage')` . What is the point of using jQuery to compare a `window.location.pathname` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it didin't return any errors neither made all the changes on switch and the nested if.

Comment: Hey Gabe. Yes I have left that jQuery on the window.pathname by mistake. I editted correctly now. :) Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.
You can write something like

```
if (condition){
    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
      execute code block 1
      break;
    case 2:
      execute code block 2
      break;
    default:
      code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
}
```

and also

```
    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
      if (condition)
        {
        code to be executed if condition is true
        }
      break;
    case 2:
      execute code block 2
      break;
    default:
      code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
```

..well I'm not going to show all the cases...

Just have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp and here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp you'll find more details also about the else statement.  And as somebody sad in the comments: try it!
Often it's the best way to understand.

Comment: Cool. I read it already. That is why I'm so intriguied with why it is not working... maybe I missed a point somewhere on the code... I don't know... Tks man! :)

Comment: I will try to execute the code on the default statement to see what happens.

Comment: Please remember to mark this as "Accepted" if it answers your question.

Comment: which kind of error you receive? Can you write the error message? Do you use an editor with syntax Highlighting? (you could avoid many errors before running the code).